# Log4j 2 memory leak

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, log4j

I use Tomcat 10.0.6, log4j 2.14.1. When I shutdown Tomcat I see this logs:

```
13-Nov-2021 22:32:32.915 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [airline] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@59402b8f]) and a value of type [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.MutableLogEvent] (value [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.MutableLogEvent@7188af83]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
13-Nov-2021 22:32:32.915 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [airline] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@6be968ce]) and a value of type [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.DatePatternConverter.PatternFormatter] (value [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.DatePatternConverter$PatternFormatter@7c37508a]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
13-Nov-2021 22:32:32.917 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [airline] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@247310d0]) and a value of type [org.apache.logging.log4j.message.ReusableSimpleMessage] (value [org.apache.logging.log4j.message.ReusableSimpleMessage@1033576a]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
13-Nov-2021 22:32:32.917 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [airline] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@303cf2ba]) and a value of type [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.DatePatternConverter.PatternFormatter] (value [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.DatePatternConverter$PatternFormatter@76494737]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
13-Nov-2021 22:32:32.921 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [airline] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@59402b8f]) and a value of type [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.MutableLogEvent] (value [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.MutableLogEvent@17fc391b]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
13-Nov-2021 22:32:32.921 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [airline] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@6be968ce]) and a value of type [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.DatePatternConverter.PatternFormatter] (value [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.DatePatternConverter$PatternFormatter@2b30a42c]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
13-Nov-2021 22:32:32.926 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [airline] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@247310d0]) and a value of type [org.apache.logging.log4j.message.ReusableSimpleMessage] (value [org.apache.logging.log4j.message.ReusableSimpleMessage@609e8838]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
```

log4j2.xml

```
<Configuration>
    <Properties>
        <Property name="property_console">%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5level %logger{1} - %msg%n</Property>
        <Property name="property_file">
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level [%t] %logger{6} - %msg%n
        </Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${property_console}"/>
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="FileRolling" fileName="logs/log.txt" append="true" filePattern="logs/${date:yyyy-MM-dd}/%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm}.txt">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${property_file}"/>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 K"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="ALL">
            <AppenderRef ref="FileRolling"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

My `log4j2` in `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I think it maybe connect with that i use `jakarta.servlet` 3.0 dependency but i don't know.
Moving .jar to tomcat/lib does not get any changes. What can be wrong?

Comment: What does visualvm (or another profiler) say is the leak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hypothesis is correct: `log4j-web` requires support for [`ServletContainerInitializer`s](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/servlet/servletcontainerinitializer), which were introduced in Servlet 3.0.

Since Servlet 5.0 (which Tomcat 10 implements), the full name of the class changed from `javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer` to `jakarta.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer` due to a copyright dispute between Oracle and the Eclipse Foundation. Therefore all versions of `log4j-web` do not work on Tomcat 10.

**Edit**: Since Log4j 2.15.0 a version of `log4j-web` supporting Jakarta EE 9+ servers is available: [`log4j-jakarta-web`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-jakarta-web), which solves the feature request [LOG4J2-2978](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-2978).